# Raffle price change on input

Tags: irc, mirc, twitch

My Code for mIRC;

```
on *:text:!raffle *:#:{
  var %hash $+(raffle.,#) 
  if ($nick isop #) && $2 == on && !$hget(%hash) { 
    hmake %hash 
  msg # The raffle now is open. Use !raffle and the amount of time you would like to enter to join. Remember, 1 entry  = 3 PuroPoints!  }
  elseif $2 isnum && $2 > 0 && $hget(%hash) {
    var %topic $+(#,.,$nick), %point $readini(points.ini,%topic,points)
    var %ra $calc( $2 * 3 - 0)
    if %point >= %ra {
      var %p $calc( %point - %ra )   
      writeini points.ini %topic points %p 
      var %i $hget(%hash,0).item, %t $calc(%i + $2) 
      while %i < %t { inc %i | hadd %hash %i $nick }
      msg # $nick $+ , You bought $2 ticket, you now have %p points
    }
    else { msg # $nick Sorry, you don't have enough PuroPoints }
  }
  elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == winner && $hget(%hash) {
    var %i $rand(1,$hget(%hash,0).data)
    msg # The winner is $hget(%hash,%i).data $+ . 
  }
  elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == over && $hget(%hash) {
    var %i $rand(1,$hget(%hash,0).data)
    hfree %hash
  }
}
```

How do I make it so that when !raffle on (number) is put in by a moderator. The number will be the price that a ticket shall cost. At the moment a ticket costs 3. 
I thought it would be like;

```
var %ra $calc( $2 * $3 - 0)
```

But it won't work>
Any ideas please

Comment: You're not clear, Please try explain yourself again.

Comment: Lets say that to enter it costs 5 points. How do i make it so if you type !raffle on 1 then it would only cost one point?

Comment: I think you should change `var %ra $calc( $2 * 3 - 0)` to `var %ra = $3`

Comment: But its the price by the amount of entrys?

Comment: Man, you really not clear. Please explain what the purposes of the relation of the `points` `on <number>`, `cost`, and `price` so I could understand what exactly you want.

Comment: You enter a raffle. You enter once by doind !raffle 1 and that would take 3 points if one entry costs 3 points and 2 entrys cost 6 points. So how can I make it that you can change the price of one entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your commentes the following should suite you well.

Change:

```
var %ra $calc( $2 * 3 - 0)
```

To:

```
var %ra = $calc($2 * %pricePerTicket)
```

And write at mIRC command the following:

```
/set %pricePerTicket 3
```

This will set the price per ticket to 3, and you can change it at will.

Comment: How do I only allow op to use t? ($nick isop #)

Comment: Yes, just add to the condition above, the line you wrote.

Comment: How would I do that :/

Comment: Change `elseif ($2 isnum && $2 > 0 && $hget(%hash)) {` to `elseif ($nick isop # && $2 isnum && $2 > 0 && $hget(%hash)) {` And consider upvote the answer.